# What does master_replid2 in Redis replication mean?

Tags: redis

I am having 1 Redis replication on my system. Last time the master_replid2 was 00000000000 but after some days it is c673350b6868f3661bd1231ad1b5389310d0a201 now. I don't know why and i have tried to searched via google but no more information about it. Can someone please tell me what it means?

I gave a look at this site but no luck: https://redis.io/commands/info

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that there are two potentially valid replication IDs: the ID1
>      * and the ID2. The ID2 however is only valid up to a specific offset. */
>    /* Use the current replication ID / offset as secondary replication
>    * ID, and change the current one in order to start a new history.
>    * This should be used when an instance is switched from slave to master
>    * so that it can serve PSYNC requests performed using the master
>    * replication ID. */

find in https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/4aa2ecd98b5993fcd6967aa002f0f7d8a577735d/src/replication.c

Comment: Thank you very much for useful information. I will give it a look right now.